# What should we use as a domain name?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name money.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

What should our domain name be?

1 name per answer, please.

Update:  Our domain name for the time being will be money.stackexchange.com.   basicallymoney.com still points and redirects to money.stackexchange.com.

This is a change in direction for the stackexchange sites and you can read a lot more information straight from the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/).

Comment: Should this be community wiki so we can use poll-style answers to gauge popularity of the various options?

Comment: See related domain naming conversations about [cooking.se](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-this-site-going-to-become-seasoned-advice-if-so-when) and [webapps.se](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com/)

Comment: `moneyoverflow.com`, or `stackofmoney.com`.

Answer (score 21):

### basicallymoney.com

if [Chris W Rea](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-w-rea) would part with it.  There is already some weight with the domain (that might be lost with this redirect)

It is a good name and already has *some* rep as this type community.

Comment: I agree that using the domain that already has a community behind it is a good idea.

Comment: @MrChrister: Yes, Stack Overflow Inc. has already made arrangements to use the domain name, should it become the best option. It would be nice to have the extra Google juice.

Comment: Yes, I agreed to have Stack Overflow Inc. acquire the domain name.  Transferring it is proving a bit more complicated than I thought, but we'll get there :-)

Comment: By the way:  **For what it's worth, the basicallymoney.com home page had/has a Google PageRank of 4 (before the migration)**

Comment: It already points here.

Comment: So does this mean this site will be BasicallyMoney despite what's happened with domain names and the other SE 2.0 sites?

Comment: @justkt - what has happened with the other sites?  I don't follow things closely enough to know.

Comment: @MrChrister - discussion here: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com/ and here: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-this-site-going-to-become-seasoned-advice-if-so-when

Comment: @MrChrister See related domain naming conversations about [cooking.se](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-this-site-going-to-become-seasoned-advice-if-so-when) and [webapps.se](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com/).   Essentially webapps was changed to nothingtoinstall.com and then changed back, also stating that se sites won't get their own domain until they hit 38K visitors/day.

Comment: Whoa, some people are getting hot under the collar.

Answer (score 1):

Something with stack and money.

Moneystack.com

Answer (score 0):

### askmoneyquestions.com

(available)

... I'm merely suggesting an alternate so it isn't only an election from the current slate of 1 name, *not that there's anything wrong with the top choice so far.*   **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

### moneybasics.com

A dark horse in the race.  No site, but it's owned ([whois](http://www.whois.net/whois/moneybasics.com)).

Answer (score 0):

### MoneyOverflow.com

Complete with a cute icon, mimicking Stack Overflow's icon, but a stack of bills instead. :D

Comment: The name is already registered but available as a "premium domain name" via GoDaddy ($688.00) ... " *GoDaddy.com does not own these names, but is one of the few registrars offering them on behalf of their third-party owners.* "

Comment: Although the design idea is nice (I had the same idea), I have to say in the long term, this isn't such a great idea.