# Moderator election: Shouldn't our moderators come from a variety of countries? Nominees wanted.

Tags: discussion, moderators

In reference to the [moderator election](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/moderator-election), first, thank you all for your support so far. **:-D**
Now, to the point of my question:

Last year, when I started *basicallymoney.com* – (the Stack Exchange 1.0 site that was [transmogrified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59672/questions-on-beta-sites-are-way-older-than-they-should-be) into this SE 2.0 site, and which [may sport that name again](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-we-use-as-a-domain-name)) – my plan was to **build a money Q&A site that was inclusive and supportive of people from multiple countries.**

Why?  Because there's so much knowledge to share about saving money, cutting costs, investing, etc. that crosses geographical boundaries.  Where boundaries matter in subjects like taxes, retirement account types, etc. our [tags](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags) support the endeavour.  Overall, I think we're better off together than apart.

(Consider [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), where Java, C#, Python, etc. developers can participate on the same site, with *many* questions of interest to all, while others specific to a choice of technology.  Works, right?)

**It was also part of my plan to have moderators that represent such a diverse user base.**
If the site has a lot of U.S. users and questions, a lot of Canadian users and questions, a lot of British users and questions, etc., then how about having moderators drawn from each group who can recognize, tag, organize, and edit questions that may be region-specific?  So:

**I'd like to make an appeal for interested users to nominate themselves for moderator.**

Both [Zephyr](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/19/zephyr) and [myself](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-w-rea) are Canadian.  We gladly accept our nominations.  But, there aren't yet any American or British nominees for moderator.  IMHO, those are gaps that should be filled ... and there will be other gaps as the site grows.  Australia? Ireland?  India?

**So... who is interested in nominating themselves for the job?**  **If so, [please do so *here*](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/moderator-election).**

Whereas, if you'd like to add your thoughts to anything I've said above, please answer below.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the main job of a moderator?  Not sure if I want to be one or not without knowing what I need to do.

Comment: The job is to help keep Q&A on the site **civil, on-topic, and somewhat organized.**  That's done by deleting abusive/offensive posts (including spam), closing questions that aren't apropos, and editing question titles, tags, and text (sometimes).

Comment: Oh, and to help **promote the site** :-D

Comment: ok.  I think I can handle that.  Sounds fun.