# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-we-use-as-a-domain-name).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Answer (score 3):

**Elevator Pitch** (and alts)

- <site name> will talk about more than you think, but it is all basically money.

**Tagline** (and alts)

- Your life is basically money

**Motto**

Basically Money

Comment: I'm a fan of the first elevator pitch item.

Comment: You are right, I should break these up

Answer (score 3):

**Elevator Pitch**:

Money. We've all got questions about it. How it works. Where to save it. How to spend it. Money.se<sup>*</sup> is where you can ask and get valuable answers on all your money questions.

**Tagline:**

Where your money questions are worth something and your answers add value!

**Motto**:

Great Money Questions and Answers. No Inflation.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Money.se is a placeholder for the site's name</sub>

Comment: I like the motto here

Comment: @MrCrister: over on [RPG.se](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/553/8) we decided to split the pieces apart to be voted on separately for that reason. I followed the current convention here, though. (ps: thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

**Tagline:**
Money Questions, Answered!

**Elevator Pitch:**
Have you ever had a difficult money question, but felt like no one wanted to give you a straight answer?  We have.  That's why our site lets you ask your questions, and get answers from other members of the community.  From buying your first house to investing in the stock market to saving for retirement, let us help find the answers you need and get on with your life. That's `<site name>`: Money Questions, Answered!

**Alternate Elevator Pitch:**
Got some extra cash, and don't know what to do with it?  Need some advice on refinancing your home?  Is that warranty policy on your new iPhone really worth the money?  These questions and more have been asked and answered on `<site name>`, and we're looking for more.  So bring us your money questions, and we'll help you get answers.  Money Questions, Answered, on `<site name>`

Comment: Are these too long?  Definitely the right idea and good content.

Answer (score 1):

**Elevator Pitch**

Basically Money: Answering your money questions

**Tagline**

Basically Money: Answering your money questions

**Motto**

Basically Money

Answer (score 1):

[answers.mint.com](http://answers.mint.com) has the **elevator pitch** *"Personal Finance Questions and Answers Community"* and its **tagline** is *"Your personal finance problems solved"*

Comment: Forgive me if I shouldn't have created a separate answer for what another, similar website is using!

Comment: basicallymoney.com used "personal finance questions and answers community" too, before we moved to money.stackexchange.com under the StackExchange 2.0 model

Answer (score 1):

**Elevator Pitch** (and alts)

- Getting control of your life and your future is basically money.

**Tagline** (and alts)

- Basically money; specifically your money

Answer (score 1):

**Elevator Pitch**

A reputation: the currency used on money.stackexchange.com to get financial questions answered.

--- or, similarily ---

Financial questions are answered at money.stackexchange.com using the most revered currency of all: a person's reputation.

**Tagline**

Financial questions answered.

**Motto**

Earn. Save. Spend.